# BIRT Report: How to group the data row wise

Tags: report, birt

I have a BIRT Report that is responsible of display medicine dispense data. In this report i have 4 columns.

1. Sl.no
2. Date
3. Pat Id
4. Patient Name
5. Doctor Name
6. Medicine Name
7. Qty

Assume that  the  patient visited the doctor, After visit, doctor assigned medicines to patient. Patient then goes and visit the pharmacy and shows the prescripton for 3 medicine. The data will appear in the report but the Name, Date, Pat Id, Patient Name, Doctor Name will appear multiple times based on the number of medicine that was dispensed. If the patient buys 3 medicines. Then above details will appear 3 times based on the medicine that was dispensed. I am getting the correct data. But i want to do some enhancement. That is as follows:

e.g: The current output as follows:

`no       Date       Patid  Patient Name       Doctor Name           Medicine          Qty`

`1.    2 Feb 2023     100       Patient A         Doc AB                Adol           30`

`2.    2 Feb 2023     100       Patient A         Doc AB                Panadol        10`

`3.    2 Feb 2023     100       Patient A         Doc AB                Paracetamol     5`

i want the below one as output in Birt report:

`no       Date       Patid  Patient Name       Doctor Name           Medicine          Qty`

`1.    2 Feb 2023     100       Patient A         Doc AB                Adol           30`

`Panadol        10`

`Paracetamol     5`

followed by the next patient data....How to achieve the above output

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to achieve, you use "Insert Group" in your report like this:
Create your plain dataset (no grouping and all) and drag&drop it on your report
[image]

then you add a group by right klick on that yellowish line
[image]

choose a fitting name and choose the objekt you want to group on and klick OK
[image]

you will see then, that there are 2 new rows in your table (header and footer of your group.
[image]

rearrange like you wish
[image]

preview your report and you will see, it has a group on whatever you choose..
[image]

you can for example now go into your report footer of your group and add an aggregation to sum up the qty of the med like:
[image]

it will suggest the grouping on patient
[image]

and you have additional info
[image]